# Cannot find module 'timers'

Tags: angular5

i use method setTimeout in my users.component.ts but does not work and get 
cannot find module 'timers' error

i import this code but does not work

```
import { setTimeout } from 'timers'
```

Comment: You don`t need to import setTimout to use it

Comment: Please provide more relevant code

Comment: @TiagoMachado My problem was solved Thanks for the guide

Answer (score 8):

I have used **SetInterval** function, Also remove the import statement that is autogenerated.

Ex :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
//import { setInterval } from 'timers';

export class HelloWorldComponent implements OnInit {

message : string ;
constructor() {

setInterval(() => {
 let currentDate = new Date();
 this.message = currentDate.toDateString() + " " + currentDate.toLocaleTimeString();
}, 1000);
}

ngOnInit() {
}

}
```

Answer (score 7):

Do not import setTimeout from 'timers'.
It will work without any importing

Answer (score 7):

Whenever you are using the setTimeout in our code,`import { setTimeout } from 'timers'`
 then this import we will get by autogenerating code, once remove this import statement and run the code it should work, for me working fine.
`

Comment: Simple yet effective solution. Thanks!