# npm Error: Cannot find module 'timers/promises'

Tags: node.js, npm

This question is NOT a duplicate of

- 69062820 [Error: Cannot find module 'timers/promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69062820)
- 66859193 [Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'timers'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66859193)
- 50136805 [Cannot find module 'timers'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50136805)

---

Upon running any `npm` commands (including when trying to install [timers-promises](https://www.npmjs.com/package/timers-promises) `npm install timers-promises`) I'm running into `Error: Cannot find module 'timers/promises'`

```
 ✘ username-2  ~/workplace/Project/src/Package  ↱ git-branch ±  npm install timers-promises                                            [Sep-28|13:45]
/local/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/es6/validate-engines.js:31
    throw err
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'timers/promises'
Require stack:
- /local/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/agent/lib/util.js
- /local/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/agent/lib/index.js
- /local/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/remote.js
- /local/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/cache/entry.js
- /local/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/cache/index.js
- /local/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/fetch.js
- /local/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/index.js
- /local/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/lib/index.js
- /local/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/replace-info.js
- /local/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-message.js
- /local/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/exit-handler.js
- /local/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli-entry.js
- /local/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js
- /local/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/local/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/agent/lib/util.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/local/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/agent/lib/util.js',
    '/local/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/agent/lib/index.js',
    '/local/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/remote.js',
    '/local/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/cache/entry.js',
    '/local/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/cache/index.js',
    '/local/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/fetch.js',
    '/local/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/index.js',
    '/local/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/lib/index.js',
    '/local/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/replace-info.js',
    '/local/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-message.js',
    '/local/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/exit-handler.js',
    '/local/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli-entry.js',
    '/local/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js',
    '/local/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
  ]
}
```

---

- I've tried installing different versions of `node` (14, 16, 20) / `npm` using `nvm` but the error continues
- I have tried this on two separate Amazon-Linux (GNU/Linux) based machines: one having x86_64 CPU and other having aarch64 (arm64) CPU and I'm getting same error on both

---

Any leads would be helpful

I'm currently on

- node v14.18.3 (a requirement for my project)
- nvm v0.39.2
- npm 6.14.18 (not sure but likely)

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning npm directories worked for me:

```bash
sudo rm -R ~/.npm ~/.nvm
```

You might need to reinstall npm after (`brew install npm` or `sudo apt install npm` or something else)